# getSupportActionBar using FragmentActivity

Tags: android, android-actionbar, android-fragmentactivity, android-support-library

I'm using fragment activity on one project, but it seems v4 support `FragmentActivity` doesn't has `getSupportActionBar()` method, and I need to use the support one in order to use `android.support.v7.app.ActionBar`

Answer (score 28, accepted):

The `ActionBarActivity` does support the method you require, and is a subclass of `FragmentActivity`.  See: http://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v7/app/ActionBarActivity.html

Comment: Can I use it for both: APIs below 11 AND above 11, or only for those below?

Comment: `ActionBarActivity` is now deprecated, use `AppCompatActivity`

Answer (score 1):

Just use `this.getActionBar()` to get action bar

Answer (score 0):

to use getSupportActionBar() you need extends ActionBarActivity  like this http://antonioleiva.com/actionbarcompat-how-to-use/

Answer (score 0):

Sameera `getSupportActionBar()` is the new way to get the `ToolBar`. In fact, `ActionBar` is now deprecated in Google Material Design.