# getActionBar doesn't work using AppCompat lib

Tags: android, intellij-idea, material-design, android-appcompat, android-actionbar-compat

I'm trying to create a TabLayout android app using `Intellij Idea` and `AppCompat v7 library`.

```
import android.support.v7.app.ActionBar;

public class MainActivity extends FragmentActivity implements TabListener { 
...
private ActionBar actionBar;
...
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
...
actionBar = getActionBar(); //Error line
...

}
```

When using `getActionBar()` I'm getting this error:

> Incompatibale types:
>
> Required: android.support.v7.app.ActionBar
>
> Found: android.app.ActionBar

I don't have `import android.app.ActionBar;` in my activity.
I tried:

```
actionBar = android.support.v7.app.ActionBar.getActionBar();
```

and

```
actionBar = getSupportActionBar();
```

But I get

> Can't resolve method getActionBar() //Or getSupportActionBar()

How can I use `getActionBar()` using appCompat library? *(Or maybe there is an alternative which I don't know about?)*

**Edit**

I also replaced `FragmentActivity` with `ActionBarActivity` in this line:

```
 public class MainActivity extends FragmentActivity //ActionBarActivity
```

But got no luck

Comment: Try this can u change FragmentActivity to AppCompatActivity and use getSupportActionBar()?

Comment: You need to `extends AppCompatActivity`, and then use `getSupportActionBar()`.

Comment: @Alex Jolig use IntelliJ Amiya's answer it'll work

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Bad Approach**

Calling older `import android.support.v7.app.ActionBar;`

If you are extending **AppCompatActivity/FragmentActivity** then you are providing backward support for older Android Versions and for that you should have to use `getSupportActionBar()`.

Read **[getSupportActionBar using FragmentActivity](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19118720/getsupportactionbar-using-fragmentactivity)**

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
  // ...

  ....

 ActionBar actionBar =getSupportActionBar();
}
```

**Add this .**

```
dependencies {
   // … 
   compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:23.1.0'
}
```

Check **[Activity, AppCompatActivity, FragmentActivity, and ActionBarActivity: When to Use Which?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31297246/activity-appcompatactivity-fragmentactivity-and-actionbaractivity-when-to-us)**

> AppCompatActivity is from the appcompat-v7 library. Principally, this
>   offers a backport of the action bar. Since the native action bar was
>   added in API Level 11, you do not need AppCompatActivity for that.

For your **[Information How do I add a library (android-support-v7-appcompat) in IntelliJ IDEA](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18025942/how-do-i-add-a-library-android-support-v7-appcompat-in-intellij-idea)**

Comment: @AlexJolig Okay , Did you compile `compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:`

Comment: @AlexJolig http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18025942/how-do-i-add-a-library-android-support-v7-appcompat-in-intellij-idea

Comment: Yes I've added the library to the project. that's why I don't get any other errors using the library

Comment: @AlexJolig Do you have `AppCompatActivity` imported in `MainActivity`?

Comment: @MikeM. That was what I missed doing this solution. Thanks

Comment: @AlexJolig No problem .Move ahead .

Answer (score 3):

First of all, you have to extends `AppCompatActivity` instead of  `FragmentActivity`.

Then you can use `getSupportActionBar()`.

To do this just import the right dependency:

```
compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:23.1.1'
```

But it is very important to chech that `TabListener` **is the wrong way to obtain a tab layout**. **This interface was deprecated in API level 21.**

With the new **Design Support Library** now you can use the new [TabLayout](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/design/widget/TabLayout.html).

Just add this dependency to your `build.gradle`

```
compile 'com.android.support:design:23.1.1'
```

The code is very simple:

```
TabLayout tabLayout = (TabLayout) findViewById(R.id.tabs);
        tabLayout.setupWithViewPager(viewPager);
```

To implement many of the features of material designs you should use it within a 
[CoordinatorLayout](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/design/widget/CoordinatorLayout.html) and a [AppBarLayout](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/design/widget/AppBarLayout.html).

Something like this:

```
 <android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout
         xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
         xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
         android:layout_width="match_parent"
         android:layout_height="match_parent">


     <android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
             android:layout_height="wrap_content"
             android:layout_width="match_parent">

         <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
                 ...
                 app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll|enterAlways"/>

         <android.support.design.widget.TabLayout
                 ...
                 app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll|enterAlways"/>

     </android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>

     <android.support.v4.view.ViewPager
        android:id="@+id/viewpager"
        app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior" />

 </android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```

Comment: What if I don't have a `build.gradle`. I'm using Intellij Idea and I didn't use Gradle. How can I compile now?

Comment: Check these links: https://www.jetbrains.com/idea/help/working-with-gradle-projects.html or https://www.jetbrains.com/idea/help/creating-a-gradle-project.html or https://www.jetbrains.com/idea/help/gradle-2.html otherwise you have to extract the classes and the resources from the aar but it is not so simple

Answer (score 0):

Change your Import

```
import android.support.v7.app.ActionBar;
```

insted of

```
import android.app.ActionBar;
```

and use

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
   // ...
}
```

Comment: Did that. Still can't use `AppCompatActivity`

Comment: compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:23.1.1' add this in your build gradle