# Use SupportActionBar with androidx FragmentActivity

Tags: android, android-actionbar, android-support-library, android-appcompat, androidx

I want to use Material Design components in my Android application. The app already uses androidx for backwards compatibility with previous versions of Android, compiling with SDK 28.

All of the activities in my application extend from a `BaseActivity` class, which in turn extends `androidx.fragment.app.FragmentActivity` (I have a camera fragment on the screen, for example).

However, when I change the theme of my application to a Material Design theme, e.g.

```xml
<style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.MaterialComponents.Light.DarkActionBar" />
```

then the MenuInflater no longer works:

```java
getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.activity_options, menu);
```

and I get a NullPointerException when trying to load the action bar (`getActionBar()` returns `null`):

```java
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
  super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
  getActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);
  ...
}
```

I have seen examples of people using `AppCompatActivity.getSupportActionBar()` elsewhere online, but this is not useful to me as `androidx.fragment.app.FragmentActivity` does not extend `AppCompatActivity`.

Is there a way to implement Material Design properly without needing to rearchitect the entire application?

Extract of the app's `build.gradle`:

```
android {
    buildToolsVersion "29.0.0"
    compileSdkVersion 28
    defaultConfig {
        minSdkVersion 19
        targetSdkVersion 23
    }
}

dependencies {
    implementation "androidx.core:core:1.1.0"
    implementation "com.google.android.material:material:1.1.0-beta01"
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> but this is not useful to me as androidx.fragment.app.FragmentActivity does not extend AppCompatActivity.

Your `BaseActivity` can extend `AppCompatActivity` instead of `FragmentActivity` since the `androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity` extends   `androidx.fragment.app.FragmentActivity`.

In this way you can use the method `AppCompatActivity.getSupportActionBar()`.

Comment: Thank you! I had just seen the answer on another question for the Android Support Library here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/19118936/9988519

Comment: @Fraser yes, the `ActionBarActivity` is an old class provided by the support libraries deprecated years ago by the `AppCompatActivity`.